# Users lose file associations to programs on logout

Tags: windows-server-2008, xenapp

OS: windows 2008 r2 with Xenapp 6.5.

Scenario: Users wants to open the same type of files in different text editing programs (Gimp, notepad++, notepad etc).

Issue: Users chose is not saved when they log out or it might be overwritten by another users chose. Here I am not sure what is going wrong.

It does not occur for all users. For example I cant replicate it with my regular non admin account. So for me all file associations are intact on log out/reboot.

I have tried to give affected users new profiles.

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with a Group Policy Setting...

Go to Start Menu -> Run -> type gpedit.msc and press Enter
Browse to User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Desktop

Make sure that the "Don't save settings at exit" is not Enabled.